# Múltiplo upload de arquivos com react.js e typescript

Tags: react, typescript, upload, formdata, multer

Estou utilizando o middleware multer para realizar o upload de arquivos , porém no front-end (com react.js) ao utilizar o form-data para pegar os arquivos selecionados pelo usuário , porém não consigo enviar para o back-end, já testei a rota de upload com o insomnia e deu tudo certo , o problema está em integrar com o react mesmo.
Dados como nome, email e senha chegam normalmente pelo formdata só que os arquivos chegam vazios (empty).

multer.ts

```
import multer from 'multer'
import path from 'path'


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) =>{
        callback(null, path.resolve(__dirname, 'uploads')  )
    },
    filename: (req, file, callback) =>{
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

const uploads = multer({ storage: storage  })

export default uploads
```

UserController.ts

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
//import knex from '../database/conn'

class UserController {
    async create(request: Request, response: Response){
        response.json({
            user_data: request.body,
            files: request.files
        })
    }
}

export default UserController
```

routes.ts

```
import express, { Router, Request, Response } from 'express'
import uploads from './multer'

import UserController from './controllers/UserController'
import MidiaController from './controllers/MidiaController'

const user_controller = new UserController()

const routes = express.Router()

//rota para cadastrado de usuário
routes.post('/cad-user', uploads.single('file'), user_controller.create)


export default routes
```

App.tsx

```
import React, { useState, ChangeEvent, FormEvent } from 'react';

import axios from 'axios'
import FormData from 'form-data'
import { Request, Response } from 'express'

import './app.css'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Input = styled.input`
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a6a6a6;
  font-size: 18px;

  margin: 5px 0px 10px 0px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 5px 10px;
`

const BtnSubmit = styled.input`
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  background-color: #2488C6;

  width: 50%;
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;

  &:hover{
    opacity: 0.85;
  };
`

const TitleForm = styled.h1`
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0px 20px 0px;
  text-align: center;
`

function App() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState()

  const [getFormData, setFormData] = useState({
    nome: '',
    email: '',
    senha: ''
  })

  const handleInputChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>{
    // console.log(event.target.name, event.target.value)
    const { name, value } = event.target


    setFormData({
      ...getFormData,
      [ name ] : value
    })
  }

  const handleInputFileChange = (e: any) =>{
      setFile(e.target.files[0])
  } 

  async function handleSubmit(event: FormEvent){
      event.preventDefault()
      console.log('Arquivo selecionado')
      console.log(file)
      const { nome, email, senha } = getFormData

      let formData = new FormData()

      formData.append('nome', nome)
      formData.append('email', email)
      formData.append('senha', senha)
      formData.append('file', file)

      axios({
        url: 'http://localhost:3030/cad-user',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
        data: formData
      })
      .then(response =>{
        console.log(response.data)
      })
      .catch(error =>{
        console.error('Erro capturado: ' + error)
      })
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TitleForm>Envie seu relato</TitleForm>
        <Input
          type="text"
          name="nome"
          id="nome"
          placeholder="Digite seu nome..."
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          multiple
        />

        <Input
          type="text"
          name="email"
          id="email"
          placeholder="Digite seu email..."
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />

        <Input
          type="password"
          name="senha"
          id="senha"
          placeholder="Digite sua senha..."
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />

        <Input
          type="file"
          name="files"
          id="files"
          onChange={handleInputFileChange}
          multiple
        />

        <BtnSubmit type="submit" value="Enviar Memória"/>

      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Observações**
Aqui eu estou atribuindo somente o primeiro arquivo selecionado pelo usuário, pois não consegui pensar em alguma maneira de enviar todos ao mesmo tempo , a ideia a princípio seria armazenar no banco de dados uma única string contendo todos os links (path) dos arquivos separados por ','(vírgula) para depois conseguir quebrar essa string com a function split, mais o problema principal está relacionado ao upload em si.

```
  const handleInputFileChange = (e: any) =>{
      setFile(e.target.files[0])
  }
```

Print do formulário

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como vocês podem ver os arquivos não aparecem para o back-end. Desde já agradeço qualquer tipo de ajuda, já pesquisei em diversos sites sobre upload de arquivos com react e typescript , mais infelizmente ainda não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, na sua rota você ta usando `upload.single()` acredito que usando desta forma, você aceitará apenas um arquivo, e não múltiplos. Senão me engano você precisa usar `upload.array('file')`.